# how to edit TimescaleStart of MS Project Using C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-project

I have a requirement to modify the ms project file (.mpp) using C#.net.

I have done with all the things, the only thing remaining is to modify the TimescaleStart date of MPP file using C#.net. I need to set the user defined date.

How can i do that?

Following is my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application();
app.DisplayAlerts = false;
app.AskToUpdateLinks = false;


app.FileOpenEx(
strFilePath + "test.mpp",
false,
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadWrite, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Project pj = app.ActiveProject;

object objDate = dt.Date;
app.TimescaleStart =   objDate;
```

Got Error  as

> Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005
>   (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))

on Following line:

```
app.TimescaleStart =   objDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

`TimescaleStart` is a **read-only** property which returns the date that the timescale starts in the current view.

If you want to scroll the view so that it starts at a certain date, find a task with a start date on or close to your target date, select it and invoke the `GotoTaskDates` method of the application object. For example:

```
 app.Find "Start", "is greater than or equal to", "1/1/2014", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing
 app.GotoTaskDates
```

**Update:**

If you are using Project 2010 or later, you can also use this method:

```
app.PanZoomPanTo (objDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you're actually trying to change the project start date?

If that's the case, try using the "ProjectMove" method. 
reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866360.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms474284%28v=office.14%29.aspx#pj14_TablesOfVBAChanges_Scheduling).

If you really really want to change TimescaleStart, [it looks like you are out of luck.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8f833236-c4cf-436d-b09a-04b3b3551a9c/setting-timescalestart-property)

Comment: Actually i am looking for the TimeScaleStart to be changed. Same i have raised to microsoft. Thank you